# How can I add a segmented control view on the storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I made my own view class and view controller class.

And I made a view controller on my storyboard and set its custom class to my own view controller class and set its view's custom class to my own view class.

After this, I wanted a segmented controller to be displayed, so I add a segmented controller on my storyboard and connected its action method with my own view controller class.

However, when I run my app, there's no segmented controller but only my own view.

How can I make my segmented controller to be displayed?

Comment: You're using autolayout?

Comment: It's most likely off screen because you didn't give it the proper constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar How can I give it the proper constraints?

Comment: You can read the documentation, and watch the videos from the 2012 WWDC, like I did. Take the time to learn it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using constraints & an `IBOutlet` to connect it. Just go to your CustomView, add an `IBOutlet` for `UISegmentedControl`. Give constraints.

If you don't know what constraints, just give horizontal & vertical align.

You will be able to see your segmented control. Cheers!